# How can i add something to the database with a submit button in Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I'm making a grocery list web app in django and i have a page with your groceries list and i have a page with all the products you can add to your list.

every product has a button "add to list". The intention is that when you click on that button that that product automatically becomes added to the groceries list. Does someone know how to do that? thank you in advance.

[The Groceries List page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOPwZ.png)

[The all products page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3Hv.png)

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AllProducts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(AllProducts, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

The class brand is a class with all the brands of the products.
The class All_Products is a class with all the products that you can add to your groceries list.
And the class ShoppingList is a class with all the products in the groceries list.

**Views.py**

```
def home(request):
    products = ShoppingList.objects.all()

    context = {
        'products':products,
    }

    return render(request, 'groceries_list/home.html', context )

def all_products(request):
    all_products = AllProducts.objects.all()
    context = {
        'products':all_products,

    }
    return render(request, 'groceries_list/all_products.html', context)
```

The home function is the function that handels the groceries list page an the all_products function is the function that handels the page with all the product you can add to your list.

***groceries list template***

```
{% extends "groceries_list/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card m-1 text-white">
      <a href="{% url 'create_grocery' %}" class="btn btn-success btn-md btn-block ">Add Grocery</a>
    </div>
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="card m-1 text-white" style="background-color: #9BD6E0;">
            <div class="card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_gorcery' product.id %}">Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_gorcery' product.id %}">Delete</a>
            <span class="text-dark"><strong>{{product.product}}</strong>  {{product.quantity}} </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

***all products template***

```
% extends "groceries_list/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card m-1 text-white">
      <a href="{% url 'create_product' %}" class="btn btn-success btn-md btn-block ">Add Product</a>

    </div>


    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="item-row">
        <div class="card m-1 text-white" style="background-color: #9BD6E0;">
            <div class="card-body">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Add To List</button>

           <span class="text-dark ml-3 text-center"><strong>{{product.name}}</strong>
             <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger float-right" href="{% url 'delete_product' product.id %}">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The site may have many `users` using it at the same time, so you should arrange for a way to identify the particular `user` who adds the item to the shopping list. The easiest way to do this is to create an authentication system (You can use as-is or extend the `User` model) from `django.auth.models`
Looking at your views, as they are, both the `home()` and and `all_products()` view are rendering the same context, which definitely can't be what is in the cart (for the home view).

A way to handle this would be to make your `ShoppingList` model in a way that it includes a field for the `customer`. The customer would be the user making the `request`.
In the `all_products.html` page, you can create a form with a hidden field that you pre-populate with the `product.id` and the 'add to list' button as a submit button for this form. 
When a user clicks 'add to list', the form gets posted to a url that invokes the responsible view. In that view, you create a '`ShoppingList object`' (an instance of the `ShoppingList` model that you created in models) with values of the `product.id` that was posted by the form and the customer as `request.user` (the user making the request).
Just a few random tips:
In your `ShoppingList model`, you are defining quantity as a `CharField` but quantity is best defined as an `IntegerField`. Also, there is no need to use both `blank=True` and `null=True` arguments. I personally like to use `blank=True` only due to safety reasons that I won't talk about here.
I would also recommend that you revise the naming systems for your models and views.

**In summary:**

- Add field customer to the ShoppingList model.
- Make field product a CharField.
- Make a form with a hidden field that posts back the product.id when a
  user clicks 'add to list'.
- Handle the post request by making a ShoppingList object.
- Consider making quantity an IntegerField.